# Как избавиться от утечки памяти Си?

Tags: c, стек

Делаю перевод выражения из одной формы в другую (обычная в постфиксную). Алгоритм перевода вроде бы работает правильно, но есть утечки в памяти.  Из-за них, похоже, программа работает через раз (иногда выдает ошибки при вытаскивании из стека вроде).  Причем когда начальная вводимая срока закончилась и остается только вытащить из стека все находящиеся там знаки операций, эти знаки операций почему-то печатаются на новой строчке(вероятно тоже все из-з утечек).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M 25
#define N 80
#define Pi 3.1415926535

void sig_handler() {
    sleep(1);
}

void catch_signal() {
    signal(SIGQUIT, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, sig_handler);
}

void graph(char **pole, double x, double y, double *y_mas);
void output(char **pole);
char *into_post();
char *post_form(char *stroka);
char **post_form1(char **stroka, unsigned long strLen);
int usleep(useconds_t usec);

struct Stack {
    char *a;
    char **str;
    int *prior;
    int size;
    int top;
};


void init(struct Stack * s) {
    s -> top = 0;
    s -> size = N;
    s -> str = malloc(s->size * sizeof(char*));
    s -> prior = malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));
}


void push_str(struct Stack * s, char *data, int prior) {
    if (s->top == s->size) {
        s->size += N;
        s->str = realloc(s->str, s->size * sizeof(char*));
        s->prior = realloc(s->prior, s->size * sizeof(int));
    }
    s->str[s->top] = data;
    s->prior[s->top] = prior;
    s->top++;
}

char *pop_str(struct Stack * s) {
    if (s->top == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    s->top--;
    return s->str[s->top];
}


void destroy(struct Stack * s) {
    while (pop_str(s)) {
 
    }
    free(s->str);
    free(s->prior);
    free(s);
    s = NULL;
}




int main() {
    char **pole;
    pole = (char**)malloc(M * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        pole[i] = (char*)malloc(N * sizeof(char));
    double x = 4*Pi/80;
    double y = (double)1/12;
    double y_mas[25];
    char *ln[2] = {"ln"};
    char *sqrt[4] = {"sqrt"};
    char *sin[3] = {"sin"};
    char *cos[3] = {"cos"};
    char *tg[2] = {"tg"};
    char *ctg[3] = {"ctg"};
    y_mas[0] = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < M; i++) {
        y_mas[i] = y_mas[i-1] + y;
    }
    
    char *stroka;
    stroka = into_post();
    char **new_str;
    unsigned long strLen = strlen(stroka);
    new_str = (char**)malloc(strlen(stroka)*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stroka); i++)
        new_str[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(stroka)*sizeof(char));
    char *str = malloc(2);
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (stroka[j]) {
        if (!(stroka[j] >= '0' && stroka[j] <= '9')) {
            str[0] = stroka[j];
            str[1] = '\0';
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
        } else if (stroka[j] >= '0' && stroka[j] <= '9') {
            while (stroka[j] >= '0' && stroka[j] <= '9') {
                str[0] = stroka[j];
                str[1] = '\0';
                strcat(new_str[i], str);
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        } else if (stroka[j] == 'c' || (stroka[j] == 's' && stroka[j+1] == 'i')) {
            str[0] = stroka[j];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+1];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+2];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            j = j + 3;
            k = k + 3;
        } else if (stroka[j] == 't' || stroka[j] == 'l') {
            str[0] = stroka[j];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+1];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            j = j + 2;
            k = k + 2;
        } else if (stroka[j] == 's') {
            str[0] = stroka[j];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+1];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+2];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            str[0] = stroka[j+2];
            strcat(new_str[i], str);
            j = j + 4;
            k = k + 4;
        }
        i++;
        if (!k)
            j++;
        k = 0;
    }
    i = 0;
    int strLen1 = j;
    post_form1(new_str, strLen1);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stroka); i++)
        free(new_str[i]);
    free(new_str);
    free(str);
    
    free(stroka);
    graph(pole, x, y, y_mas);
    output(pole);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        free(pole[i]);
    free(pole);
}


char **post_form1(char **stroka, unsigned long strLen) {
    struct Stack *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    init(s);
    char **exit_str;
    int save = strLen;
    exit_str = (char**)malloc(strLen*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
        exit_str[i] = (char*)malloc(strLen*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    strLen--;
    while (strLen) {
        strLen--;
        if (strcmp(stroka[i], "(") == 0) {

            push_str(s, stroka[i], 0);
        } else if (!strcmp(stroka[i], "-") || !strcmp(stroka[i], "+")) {
            while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 1) {

                exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
                j++;
            }

            push_str(s, stroka[i], 1);
        } else if (!strcmp(stroka[i], "/") || !strcmp(stroka[i], "*")) {
            while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 2) {

                exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
                j++;
            }

            push_str(s, stroka[i], 2);
        } else if (!strcmp(stroka[i], "^")) {
            while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 3) {

                exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
                j++;
            }

            push_str(s, stroka[i], 3);
        } else if (!strcmp(stroka[i], "~")) {
            while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 4) {

                exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
                j++;
            }

            push_str(s, stroka[i], 4);
        }
 /*       if (stroka[i] == 'c') {
            char *comb = (char[]){stroka[i], stroka[i+1], stroka[i+2]};
            while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 5) {
                exit_str[j] = ' ';
                j++;
                exit_str[j] = pop(s);
                j++;
            }
            exit_str[j] = ' ';
            j++;
            push_str(s, comb, 5);
            i = i + 2;
        } */
        else if (!strcmp(stroka[i], ")")) {
            while (strcmp(s->str[s->top-1], "(") != 0) {

                exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
                j++;
            }
            pop_str(s);
        } else {
            exit_str[j] = stroka[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    while (s->top != 0) {
        exit_str[j] = pop_str(s);
        j++;
    }
    destroy(s);
    i = 0;
    while(exit_str[i]) {
        printf("%s", exit_str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(exit_str);
    return exit_str;
}


char *into_post() {
    char *stroka;
    stroka = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &stroka[i])) {
        stroka = (char*)realloc(stroka, sizeof(char));
        if (stroka[i] == '\n')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return stroka;
}

void graph(char **pole, double x, double y, double *y_mas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            pole[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    double y_count[80];
    double x_count = 0;
    //Вместо этого по идее мы должны сами вводить функцию
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        y_count[j] = sin(cos(2*x_count));
        x_count = x_count + x;
    }
    //
    
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        int k = 0;
        if (y_count[j] <= 1 && y_count[j] >= -1) {
            while (y_mas[k] < y_count[j] && k < M - 1) {
                k++;
            }
            if (y_count[j] - y_mas[k] > y_mas[k-1] - y_count[j]) {
                pole[k][j] = '*';
            } else {
                pole[k-1][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
}

void output(char **pole) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
            printf("%c ", pole[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%c", pole[i][N - 1]);
        if (i != M - 1) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Код немного (много) страшный, но причесывать потом буду, сейчас хотя бы работать заставить его нормально нужно.

Вообще Xcode при выводе (когда сработало) выдает такое: `5cosxsqrt2542/--tg25x ectionViewItem setRepresentedObject:]+` То есть все перевел, но когда осталось только достать последние элементы из стека, печатает что-то непонятное и оставшиеся в стеке элементы распечатывает на новой строке.

Сейчас позапускал (с 5го раза выдал ошибку, вбивал одну и ту же строку. `while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 2) {` Показал, что остановился в этом месте. Сама ошибка: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc)`. Могу предположить, что я как-то неправильно очищаю строку в стеке.

Еще вот что могу сказать. Если я удалю весь цикл `while (stroka[j])`, и добавлю очищение памяти перед `free(exit_str);` вот такое:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < save; i++) //save -  длина строки заданная в начале
        free(new_str[i]);
```

То утечек нет. Однако если я без удаления цикла разбора строки пропишу такое же очищение `free(new_str[i]);`, вылезает ошибка, что он пытается очистить то для чего памяти выделено не было.

Закомментил все присваивание `exit_str[j]`, утечек нет, значит по идее проблема не в стеке,  а в очистке `exit_str[j]`

Comment: а на эти ошибки можно взглянуть? может вы их приложите?

Comment: Вообще Xcode при выводе (когда сработало) выдает такое: '5cosx*sqrt2542/--tg25x*
ectionViewItem setRepresentedObject:]+' То есть все перевел, но когда осталось только достать последние элементы из стека, печатает что-то непонятное и оставшиеся в стеке элементы распечатывает на новой строке.

Comment: Сейчас позапускал (с 5го раза выдал ошибку, вбивал одну и ту же строку. 'while (s->prior[s->top-1] >= 2) {' Показал, что остановился в этом месте. Сама ошибка: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffffc). Могу предположить,  что я как-то неправильно очищаю строку в стеке.

Comment: нажмите на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1447534/edit) и приложите все это в текст вопроса

Comment: Добавил все что можно наверное.

Comment: *"Добавил все что можно наверное."* - а надо было составить [mcve] Вообще тут полный швах и с выделением памяти, и обращениями по индексам, а до освобождения памяти дело видимо даже не доходит, так как куча уже повреждена.